# Execute bash scripts on entering a directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, cd-command

What is the best way to execute a script when entering into a directory?
 When I move into a new directory I would like bash to execute the projectSettings.bash script much like RVM does.

Comment: Into every directory, or selected ones? And the same script for each, or not?

Comment: Every directory. The script in the directory named projectSettings.bash if it exists.

Comment: [Similar question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276247/is-there-a-hook-in-bash-to-find-out-when-the-cwd-changes)

Comment: Try direnv with `.envrc` files: https://direnv.net/

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can make `cd` a function (and `pop` and `pushd`), and make it detect if you enter that particular directory.

```
cd () { builtin cd "$@" && chpwd; }
pushd () { builtin pushd "$@" && chpwd; }
popd () { builtin popd "$@" && chpwd; }
unset_all_project_settings () {
  # do whatever it takes to undo the effect of projectSettings.bash,
  # e.g. unset variables, remove PATH elements, etc.
}
chpwd () {
  case $PWD in
    /some/directory|/some/other/directory) . ./projectSettings.bash;;
    *) unset_all_project_settings;;
  esac
}
```

Do not do this in directories that you haven't whitelisted, because it would make it very easy for someone to trick you into running arbitrary code — send you an archive, so you unzip it, change into the directory it created, and you've now run the attacker's code.

I don't recommend this approach, because it means the script will be executed even if you enter that directory for some reason that's unrelated to working on the project. I suggest having a specific function that changes to the project directory and sources the settings script.

```
myproj () {
  cd /some/directory && . ./projectSettings.bash
}
```

Comment: I only started in Ruby a little while ago. The RVM tool tho is completely in Bash and one of the best pieces of Bash magic I have seen. I think the answer is a little silly because one of the absolutely worse things you can ever do is over ride something like `cd` and there is with out doubt a better way. Even using $PROMPT_COMMAND is better!

Comment: @JamesAndino In zsh I'd use `chpwd`. Lacking an exact equivalent in bash, overloading `cd` feels reasonable. With `PROMPT_COMMAND`, your per-directory settings will be set later if you run `cd foo; somecommand` and not at all if you run `(cd foo; somecommand)` (this may or may not be what you want).

Comment: They do it here using just BASH with out overloading PROMPT_COMMAND or cd  https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm I tried to unlock the secret but failed.

Comment: I was completely wrong and apologize. RVM was overloading cd.

Comment: (removed some tangential pro/anti-Ruby stuff from this comment thread)

Comment: In our work environment we already use aliases to nav to the common repos, thus the *last* part of this answer is the most useful for us.  Thanks!

Comment: in the projectSettings.bash I suggest you to add a flag variable to not repeat the initialization in case you exit/re-enter the directory. So enclose everything in `if [ -z $MYSETTINGS ] ; then export MYSETTINGS=1 ; echo your settings here ; fi`. This is to avoid problems in case you do something PATH=/mytools/bin:$PATH kind of initialisation.

Comment: @spider Rather there should be some kind of unset mechanism if you leave the directory. If you leave and reenter, you should get the settings back!

Comment: @Gilles Yeah, you're right.

Comment: +1 Nice, elegant, and does not need an external dependency.

Answer (score 12):

[direnv](https://direnv.net/) might be what you are looking for.

> `direnv` is an extension for your shell. It augments existing shells with a new feature that can load and unload environment variables depending on the current directory.

Here is an example taken from the official documentation:

```
$ cd ~/my_project
$ echo ${FOO-nope}
nope
$ echo export FOO=foo > .envrc
.envrc is not allowed
$ direnv allow .
direnv: reloading
direnv: loading .envrc
direnv export: +FOO
$ echo ${FOO-nope}
foo
$ cd ..
direnv: unloading
direnv export: ~PATH
$ echo ${FOO-nope}
nope
```

Answer (score 4):

It's my cd function

```bsh
function cd()
{
    if [ -f .exit.sh ]; then
        source .exit.sh;
    fi

    if [ -z $* ]; then
        builtin cd ~
    else
        builtin cd "$*"
    fi

    if [ -f .enter.sh ]; then
        source .enter.sh;
    fi
}
```

And then you can write your script in ".enter.sh" or ".exit.sh".

Comment: Replace the whle middle `if [ -z $* ]` (which breaks if you pass cd more than 1 argument) with one line: `builtin cd "$@"`

Comment: With this approach: any evil user can put harmful scripts in some path (ex: inside /tmp ? ) and you will execute whatever command there is inside those harmfull scripts whenever you cd into (or cd from) those path... It is incredibly dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

[ondir](https://swapoff.org/ondir.html) is another alternative to run scripts  as you enter directories in a terminal.