# Run a script automatically as I switch to a directory

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, cd-command

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Execute bash scripts on entering a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21363/execute-bash-scripts-on-entering-a-directory)

I am running an environment which requires some very specific tool versions.
The commands to set up the environment are in a script called `set_foo_env.sh`

Suppose I have a directory `~/repository/foo/`. Is is possible to run `set_foo_env.sh` as soon as I enter the `foo` directory?

Comment: The question, I accept might be similar. But one of the answers listed below here by @nsg is very interesting and novel. I am yet to try this solution out and rate it. I think this might work better than using aliasing `cd` although this is my personal opinion. Thanks for your comment though.

Comment: Depends on your goal. The `PROMPT_COMMAND` based solution will run the command after each command executed inside the specified directory. So if you do `cd ~/repository/foo/`, `du -sch` and `date`, then set_foo_env.sh will be executed 3 times. The `cd` aliasing solution will execute it only once.

Answer (score 7):

You could use PROMPT_COMMAND, the code specified in PROMPT_COMMAND is executed before bash draws the prompt.

```
# Call function 'foo'
PROMPT_COMMAND=foo

# The function
foo() {
        if [[ $PWD == "$HOME/repository/foo" ]]; then
              set_foo_env.sh  
        fi
}
```

Note, PROMPT_COMMAND is bash specific, and this is not a efficient way because the function foo will be called every time bash draws the prompt.

Comment: Shouldn't that be either "$HOME/repository/foo" or "/home/$USER/repository/foo"? And the trailing slash may be a problem, at least my `bash` sets `$PWD` without it.

Comment: Also, this seems to be `bash`-specific. It doesn't work on my old `ksh`.

Comment: This isn't a good solution because it runs the command every time the prompt is displayed, not after a `cd`.

Comment: Yes, PROMT_COMMAND is bash-specific. The question contains the tags 'bash' so i assumed he was a bash user. The cd-function trick suggested by Arcege may be a better solution, note the possible security concern stated by jw013.

Comment: manatwork: true, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Change the `cd` into a function to run the real `cd` and run your script afterward.

```
cd () {
    if builtin cd ${1:+"$@"} && [ -r ./set_foo_env.sh ]; then
        . ./set_foo_env.sh
    fi
}
```

This assumes that:

1. The `set_foo_env.sh` would be specific to a single directories, and
2. That `set_foo_env.sh` should change the existing shell's environment.

If you want path-based with a global file, then look at the question that manatwork mentioned ( [Execute bash scripts on entering a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21363/execute-bash-scripts-on-entering-a-directory)).

Comment: It should be mentioned that this particular implementation does open up a serious security hole.  Never `cd` to any directory other users can drop files into (like a dropbox or Public directory, e.g. `rm -f ~you/Public/set_foo_env.sh; echo $'#!/bin/sh\nchmod -R 777 ~' > ~you/Public/set_foo_env.sh`).