# How to set dotenv variables in bash shell when changing directory?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, prompt

I'm trying to set custom environment variables when changing to a particular directory that has a `.env` file containing the variables. In order for it to be triggered automatically, I included the following code inside my `.bashrc` file.

```
...

__dotenv() {

    if [ -f .env ]; then        
        set -o allexport
        source .env
        set +o allexport
        echo "ε "
    fi
}

PS1="$MSYSTEM \w \$(__dotenv)$ "
...
```

This way, whenever I change to a folder that has a `.env` file, it is supposed to load the environment variables specified in it. For example in directory `/d/Project/project1` I have the following `.env` file:

```
ENV_VAR1=/path/to/project1
ENV_VAR2=/path/to/project2
```

When I run the `cd` command:

```
MINGW64 / $ cd /d/Projects/project1
MINGW64 /d/Projects/project1 ε $ env | grep ENV_VAR
```

nothing gets set from the `.env` file. I can tell that the function is executed as the ε indicator shows up in the prompt. However, if I run the `__dotenv` function directly,

```
MINGW64 /d/Projects/project1 ε $ __dotenv
ε 
MINGW64 /d/Projects/project1 ε $ env | grep ENV_VAR
ENV_VAR1=/path/to/project1
ENV_VAR2=/path/to/project2
```

they are set properly. Is there a specific syntax in calling the function similar to doing a `source` on a bash script?

Comment: You are sourcing something in a subshell (because of the command substitution), so all your exported variables are only in that subshell.

Comment: Is there any way to invoke that function in the current shell (and not the subshell)?

Comment: Use `PROMPT_COMMAND` instead: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42736/70524

Comment: Thanks @muru, that actually does exactly what I need.