# Show only current and parent directory in bash prompt

Tags: bash, prompt

I'm new to bash and would like my prompt to show something that in tcsh was trivial, yet after a good google search I still cannot do.

I would like my prompt to include only the current and parent directories like this:

```
/parent/currentdir $
```

In tcsh this is achieved by:

```
set prompt = "%C2 %"
```

However in bash so far I have only found that I have to parse pwd to obtain the same output.

Isn't there a simpler way, like doing:

```
export PS1="$(some_command) $"
```

Comment: In theory, `PS1='\w \$'; PROMPT_DIRTRIM=2` should give you the bash equivalent, but that doesn't work properly on my system.

Comment: It doesn't work at all on mine: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14).

Comment: `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` was introduced in [Bash 4](https://seasonofcode.com/posts/shortening-paths-in-the-bash-prompt-with-prompt_dirtrim.html). I just tested on Ubuntu 16.04 under WSL and it worked great!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Bash's [prompt control](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt) features are rather static. If you want more control, you can include variables in your prompt; make sure you haven't turned off the [`promptvars` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin).

```
PS1='${PWD#"${PWD%/*/*}/"} \$ '
```

Note the single quotes: the variable expansions must happen at the time the prompt is displayed, not at the time the `PS1` variable is defined.

If you want more control over what is displayed, you can use command substitutions. For example, the snippet above loses the `~` abbreviation for the home directory.

```
PS1='$(case $PWD in
        $HOME) HPWD="~";;
        $HOME/*/*) HPWD="${PWD#"${PWD%/*/*}/"}";;
        $HOME/*) HPWD="~/${PWD##*/}";;
        /*/*/*) HPWD="${PWD#"${PWD%/*/*}/"}";;
        *) HPWD="$PWD";;
      esac; printf %s "$HPWD") \$ '
```

This code is rather cumbersome, so instead of sticking it into the `PS1` variable, you can use the [`PROMPT_COMMAND` variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PROMPT_005fCOMMAND) to run code to set `HPWD` and then use that in your prompt.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='case $PWD in
        $HOME) HPWD="~";;
        $HOME/*/*) HPWD="${PWD#"${PWD%/*/*}/"}";;
        $HOME/*) HPWD="~/${PWD##*/}";;
        /*/*/*) HPWD="${PWD#"${PWD%/*/*}/"}";;
        *) HPWD="$PWD";;
      esac'
PS1='$HPWD \$'
```

Since the shortened prompt only changed on a directory change, you don't need to recalculate it each time a prompt is displayed. Bash doesn't provide a hook that runs on a current directory change, but you can [simulate it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21363/execute-bash-scripts-on-entering-a-directory/21364#21364) by overriding `cd` and its cousins.

```
cd () { builtin cd "$@" && chpwd; }
pushd () { builtin pushd "$@" && chpwd; }
popd () { builtin popd "$@" && chpwd; }
chpwd () {
  case $PWD in
    $HOME) HPWD="~";;
    $HOME/*/*) HPWD="${PWD#"${PWD%/*/*}/"}";;
    $HOME/*) HPWD="~/${PWD##*/}";;
    /*/*/*) HPWD="${PWD#"${PWD%/*/*}/"}";;
    *) HPWD="$PWD";;
  esac
}
PS1='$HPWD \$'
```

Note that you don't need to, and should not, export `PS1`, since it's a shell setting, not an environment variable. A bash `PS1` setting wouldn't be understood by other shells.

P.S. If you want a nice interactive shell experience, switch to [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/), where all of these (prompt `%` expansions largely encompassing tcsh's, `chpwd`, etc.) are native features.

```
PS1='%2~ %# '
```

Comment: Consider using a *function* instead of *a script in a variable*! See [my answer to Git bash doesn't recognize 'rev' command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55938151/1765658)

Answer (score 15):

Setting `PROMPT_DIRTRIM=2` should be all you need.

Comment: Noting the comments https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216953/show-only-current-and-parent-directory-in-bash-prompt#comment368350_216953 and following

Comment: This is the idomatic way to do this, and should be the accepted answer.  note that this makes the prompt say .../parent/current, which is slightly different than the request, but is better, IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

Prompt string can be easily changed in `bash` by editing the shell variable `PS1`. It stands for Prompt String 1. More info [here](http://www.linuxnix.com/2013/04/linuxunix-shell-ps1-prompt-explained-in-detail.html).

For now fire up your `bash` shell.

`vi ~/.bashrc`

Append the PS1 definition in the file

```
`export PS1="$(basename $(dirname $PWD))/$(basename $PWD)"`
```

More tutorials [here](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Changing_bash_prompt) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-customize-your-bash-prompt-on-a-linux-vps), to help you tweak it even more.

Comment: I understand how to modify the prompt. My question is how to get only the current and parent directories, not the whole path.

Comment: @twalbaum edited my answer

Comment: glad to help @twalbaum :)

Comment: This sets the prompt to the current directory at the time `.bashrc` is loaded, the prompt won't change if you `cd` into another directory! @twalbaum

Comment: @Gilles it does for me.

Comment: @twalbaum If it does, either you're using different code from Munai's or you have something else overriding your prompt.

Comment: @Gilles You are right. By itself it doesn't work as expected. I was looking for the syntax and placing it within code of my own. What should I do? Write the way I am doing it in a new answer? Not sure I can explain it correctly as a comment...

Comment: @twalbaum Answering your own question is perfectly fine, it's encouraged if you managed to find a solution on your own, even if one answer gave you a hint but was missing some critical elements.

Comment: Apparently you'll also need some quoting around `$PWD`, for cases where the value of `$PWD` contains spaces or other troublesome characters.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for obtaining the parent and current directories is taken from Munai's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216957/104149).

However, as noted by Gilles, that code only shows the current directory at the time `.bashrc` is loaded, but it won't change as you navigate the system to other folders.

Having this in your `.bashrc` file makes the prompt automatically updated to your current directory:

```
prompt_command () {
    PS1='$(basename $(dirname "$PWD"))/$(basename "$PWD") $ '
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

Comment: Is defining `prompt_command()` supposed to do something, on its own? It doesn't for me. Did you mean to also use `prompt_command()` in redefinitions of `cd` & co, like Gilles did? Or did you mean `PROMPT_COMMAND='...'`?

Comment: Also, this command fails when `$PWD` contains a space.

Comment: Thank you for bringing me back to this. Quoted the $PWDs to allow for spaces and included the final command. My current prompt is more complex than this, therefore the need for the prompt_command definition. Otherwise, PS1=... works on its on.

Comment: Any ideas for cleaning up the output when navigating to `/`? As written, you get `/// $ `

Comment: Has anyone been able to develop a similar solution for Windows Command Prompt and/or PowerShell? When I use `for %I in (.) do prompt %~nxI$G`, the current folder is displayed, but it is not dynamic. So, it won't change when I change folders. Reference: [Get current folder name by a DOS command?](https://superuser.com/questions/160702/get-current-folder-name-by-a-dos-command/)

Comment: Solutions using PowerShell can be found here: [Configure Windows PowerShell to display only the current folder name in the shell prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/446827/configure-windows-powershell-to-display-only-the-current-folder-name-in-the-shel). 

Example provide by @Jelgab: `Function Prompt { "$( ( get-item $pwd ).Name )>" }`

Answer (score 2):

Adding `export PROMPT_DIRTRIM=2` to your bash file will do it for recent versions of bash (v. 4+). Specifically, this alters the appearance of the `\w` entry in the `PS1` environment variable from full path to last two entries.

Final results looks like `../Documents/MyFolder`

Answer (score -1):

May be simpler one with "~" for Home directory.

```
function PWDN {
  echo "${PWD/#$HOME/~}" | rev | cut -d "/" -f1 -f2 | rev
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
export PS1='[\u@\h $(basename $(dirname ${PWD}))/$(basename ${PWD})]\$ '
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;$(basename $(dirname $PWD))/$(basename ${PWD})\007"'
```

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).