# Setting up command promt in tcsh to show only last 3 working directory instead of complete path?

Tags: prompt, tcsh

I have command prompt in tcsh that shows the current working directory. The problem is that the command prompt becomes very big once I am in a deep hierarchy of folders. How do I set the command prompt to show, let's say, only the last 3 directory names?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216953/show-only-current-and-parent-directory-in-bash-prompt), you can achieve that by setting:

```
set prompt = "%C3 %"
```

This should show you last three directory names of your CWD, followed by a space and a percent sign.