# Set PS1 based on the number of jobs

Tags: bash, prompt

From Bash's manual (Controlling the Prompt][1](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html)):

```
\j the number of jobs currently managed by the shell.  

\$ If the effective uid is 0, #, otherwise $.
```

**What I'd like** is to set `PS1` to

```
[some-string] $
```

when there are no jobs; and

```
[some-string]2 $
```

when there are 2 jobs.

How I could I achieve that?

If possible, the solution could be simple, with only basic Bash expansions and possibly Bash builtins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Bash supports conditionals in the prompt (like e.g. `screen` does, IIRC), but you could use command substitution with `\j` to add some logic over it.

```
anyjobs() { [[ "$1" != 0 ]] && echo "[ $1 bg job(s) ] "; }
PS1='$? $(anyjobs \j)\u@\h \w\$ '
```

That does run a subshell, which involves a `fork()` in Bash, but I can't see a way around that.

In general, you could avoid the subshell by setting a variable in `PROMPT_COMMAND`, but I can't see a simple way to get the number of jobs there.

Comment: Many thx, really helpful. PROMPT_COMMAND? maybe similar to this (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217097/202329), though I cannot solve it currently.

Comment: @qeatzy, Bash runs whatever code there is in the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable before printing each (primary) prompt. So you could set a variable there, and use it in `PS1`. E.g. something like `PROMPT_COMMAND='((i += 3))'; PS1='$i \u@\h \w\$ '` (of course you can also call a function in `PROMPT_COMMAND` to make it cleaner)

Comment: So yeah, pretty much what that answer also does. Though with the 7-line `case` in there, I'd definitely put it in a function.

Comment: indeed, the function solution is cleaner.