# Conditional PS1

Tags: bash, git, prompt

I'm basically trying to make my PS1 look like this when in a git repo:

```
$ ~/Projects/Blah (master):
```

Or if I'm not in a Git repo, I want it to look like this:

```
$ ~/Projects/Blah:
```

This is my current PS1:

```
export PS1="$ \w \$(__git_ps1): "
```

It works for the git repo output, but the problem is that if I'm not in a git repo, the output looks like this:

```
$ ~/Projects/Blah :
```

I don't really want that space there if it isn't a git repo, is there some way I can specify this in my PS1?

Comment: maybe? `export PS1="$ \w \$(__git_ps1 | sed 's/^ $//'): "`

Comment: The space that you are referring is the one that appears before the colon?, in that case try:
`export PS1="$\w\$(__git_ps1):"`
that will remove the space, it's not related to the result of `__git_ps1`

Comment: Hmm @JeffSchaller that didn't seem to fix it I still get the space before the colon. @Moises, the the problem with that is that I get an output like this: `$ ~/Projects/Blah(master):`. I want a space before the parentheses if it is a git repo.

Comment: You can use a function that sets `PS1` using the `PROMPT_COMMAND` bash variable. See: [PS1 example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30963255/5032992)

Comment: I use ```\[\033[01;32m\]\w\[\033[01;33m\]$(__git_ps1 " (%s)") \[\033[01;37m\]\$``` and that never puts in extra spaces if I'm not in a git folder.

Comment: @meh_programmer, I apologize for not fully understanding the question and being late to suggest the usage of a format string. i think that with the format string is enough and you will not need the sourcing that you are doing previously. BR

Comment: The answer given by @Saad below was super helpful and solved this exact issue very elegantly. Recommend folks give it a whirl. Super easy to setup too because of the include script reference.

Answer (score 3):

What I do for this kind of thing is to change the value of `PS1` when I change directories. This is trivial in zsh which executes the `chpwd` command; it can be done in bash by [defining wrappers around `cd` and friends](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21363/execute-bash-scripts-on-entering-a-directory/21364#21364).

```
cd () { builtin cd "$@" && chpwd; }
pushd () { builtin pushd "$@" && chpwd; }
popd () { builtin popd "$@" && chpwd; }
chpwd () {
  if git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>/dev/null >/dev/null; then
    PS1='$ \w $(__git_ps1): '
  else
    PS1='$ \w: '
  fi
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried this out, but the `else` part seems to never run, even when I'm in a directory that is a git repo. It seems to always be using `PS1='$ \w: '`.

Comment: @meh_programmer I'd swapped the two branches, it should work now.

Answer (score 3):

I use a `function` to set my prompt dynamically. Here is my particular function, defined in my development environment initialisation script:

```
function prompt_cmd
{
  # Tell the terminal application (using escape sequences) what the CWD is.
  # (this comes from /etc/bashrc)
  update_term_cwd

  if [[ "$ORIG_PS1" == "" ]]; then
    export ORIG_PS1=$PS1
  fi

  if [[ "$CURRENT_PROJECT" == "" ]]; then
    export PS1=$ORIG_PS1
  else
    if [[ "$PWD" == "$DEV_HOME/projects/$CURRENT_PROJECT"* ]]; then
       PWD_COLOR=''
    else
       PWD_COLOR='\[\e[0;31m\]'
    fi
    export PS1="\[\e[0;32m\]$CURRENT_PROJECT\[\e[m\]:$PWD_COLOR\W\[\e[m\]$ "
  fi
}
```

(it sets the path part of the prompt to red if I happen to drift out of the project I think I'm in!)

...then tell bash to use the function:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_cmd
```

Comment: Interesting to see from the `.git-prompt.sh` example above that you can evaluate functions in the PS1 environment variable's value - I didn't know this. Another good way of doing it! (e.g. `export PS1='$(myps1fun) other stuff $ '`)

Comment: `update_term_cwd` seems to be a deprecated Apple OS command.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using this [`.git-prompt.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) file. Steps to get this to work:

1. Create a file called `.git-prompt.sh` in your home directory (`~/.git-prompt.sh`) and copy the code from the link above into it.
2. In your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file, add this line: `source ~/.git-prompt.sh`
3. Change your PS1 to this: `PS1='\n$ \w$(__git_ps1 " (%s)"): '`

Comment: The key to that working is the ```%s``` in ```$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")```.

Comment: Super helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;$( [ "$PS1TITLE" == "" ] || echo -n "$PS1TITLE  :  ")${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

When the variable PS1TITLE is set, its contents shows up in the window's titlebar.

Explanation:

```
PS1='...'
```

Make no variable expansion.

```
PS1='...$( [ "$PS1TITLE" == "" ] || echo -n "$PS1TITLE  :  ")...'
```

Execute a test: if variable "PS1TITLE" is empty, do not display it. If the string exists and is non-empty, it is displayed with a colon.

The rest of the PS1 string is taken from a Debian system's .bashrc.

Bash executes PS1 every time prompt is displayed and updates everything accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux and thanks for taking the time to answer this question. While your answer might be correct many readers might appreciate a short explanation _how_ this solves the problem. You can edit your question at any time.

Answer (score 0):

```
# .bashrc example edits to PS1 for git
```

## With Abbreviated Paths:

```
    # -- With color:
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[01;33m\]$([[ "$(git branch --show-current 2>/dev/null)" == "" ]] || echo " ("$(git branch --show-current 2>/dev/null)")")\[\033[00m\]\$ '

    # -- Without color:
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\W$([[ "$(git branch --show-current 2>/dev/null)" == "" ]] || echo " ("$(git branch --show-current 2>/dev/null)")")\$ '
```

## As Requested:

```
    # -- With color:
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;33m\]$([[ "$(git branch --show-current 2>/dev/null)" == "" ]] || echo " ("$(git branch --show-current 2>/dev/null)")")\[\033[00m\]: '

    # -- Without color:
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$([[ "$(git branch --show-current 2>/dev/null)" == "" ]] || echo " ("$(git branch --show-current 2>/dev/null)")"): '
```

[image: From a KDE Plasma Bash Konsole]