# Prompt to reflect sshfs mountpoint?

Tags: arch-linux, zsh, prompt, sshfs

I use `sshfs` to remotely mount a remote folder to my local machine, the problem is that I need a way to know that I'm working under remote folder on local machine OR `local` folder to avoid accidentally do harm to remote one.

How to have zsh/bash prompt to reflect that I'm currently in remote mountpoint so I will do actions more carefully?

Example: sshfs  
now when I cd to `local_of_remote_mountpoint`, the prompt will notify me that this is folder that was mounted using `sshfs` like: `user@host: sshfs% ls`

Comment: Is it your aim to have your shell's prompt remind you of the mount point you are on (e.g. setting `PS1` in your shell's startup file), or to have `cd` emit a warning when you enter a remote directory (e.g. defining a `cd` function that wraps the `cd` command)?

Comment: Probably not, as in example in my post, in reality I would use a symbol with maybe `red` color instead of `sshfs` in prompt, I don't need to know `path` - mountpoint. But `zsh` should check if the folder is a mountpoint that mounted with sshfs somehow. @fra-san

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We face two distinct issues here:

1. How to know if the current working directory (PWD) is on a filesystem mounted by `sshfs`;
2. How to reflect point 1 in the shell prompt.

#### Is the current working directory part of a filesystem mounted by `sshfs`?

Comparing PWD with mount points is not reliable. It may not work, for instance, if a component of your PWD is a symbolic link to a mount point.

On GNU/Linux, tools as `df` and `findmnt` are able to determine the mount point a directory is on. Also, both can report the `FSTYPE` attribute of a filesystem, that is set to `fuse.sshfs` for those mounted by `sshfs`.

You can thus check with:

```sh
# df always prints a header line, we want to skip it
[ "fuse.sshfs" = "$(df --output=fstype . | tail -n +2)" ] && ...
```

or:

```sh
[ "fuse.sshfs" = "$(findmnt --noheadings --output=FSTYPE --target .)" ] && ...
```

You can wrap this test in a script and make it available in your `PATH`. Here we will call it `check_sshfs_mp`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
[ "fuse.sshfs" = "$(findmnt --noheadings --output=FSTYPE --target .)" ] && exit 0
exit 1
```

#### How to set the shell prompt based on the mount point we are on?

In both `bash` and `zsh` you can set the `PS1` shell variable, which is expanded as the primary prompt.

In `bash` you can do it in wrappers for the relevant functions: `cd`, `pushd` and `popd` (credits: [thanks to this answer to "Conditional PS1"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280934/315749) for reminding me `cd` is not the only one), adding this code to your `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
cd () { builtin cd "$@" && chpwd; }

pushd () { builtin pushd "$@" && chpwd; }

popd () { builtin popd "$@" && chpwd; }

chpwd () {
    normal='\[\e[0m\]'
    red='\[\e[1;31m\]'
    PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
    if command -v check_sshfs_mp > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        check_sshfs_mp && PS1='[\u@\h '"$red"'R'"$normal"' \W]\$ '
    fi
}
```

The `chpwd` function invokes `check_sshfs_mp` and, if its exit status is `0`, adds a single red `R` letter to `PS1`.
You may want to adjust the default value of `PS1` according to your preferences.

In `zsh` it is somehow easier, since `zsh` executes the `chpwd` special function whenever the current working directory is changed (references: The Z Shell Manual, [Special Functions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Special-Functions)). You can add a prompt-setting function to the array of hook functions that are executed along with `chpwd`.
Assuming you are not using [user contributions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html) that interfere with prompt setting, you can add this code to your `~/.zshrc`:

```sh
chpwd_check_sshfs_mp () {
    PS1='%m%# '
    if command -v check_sshfs_mp > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        check_sshfs_mp && PS1='%m %F{red}R%f %# '
    fi
}
chpwd_functions+=( chpwd_check_sshfs_mp )
```

Again, we are simply adding a red `R` to the primary prompt when `chech_sshfs_mp` succeeds.

Note that wrapping `cd` and adding a `chpwd_functions` hook function will not ensure the prompt is set correctly if the PWD your terminal is started in is on a `sshfs` mounted filesystem. You will need at least a `cd` to trigger the correct prompt, and this may be misleading.

User contributions to `zsh` that perform prompt theming will require *ad-hoc* solutions to customize prompts.
You can nevertheless shut down prompt theming with

```sh
prompt off
```

to experiment with this code.

---

Integrating points brought up in comments about `zsh`:

If you prefer to specify prompt coloring with [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) (instead of color names) you may change the `PS1` assignment line in the above code snippet to:

```sh
check_sshfs_mp && PS1="$(print '%m %{\e[1;31m%}R%{\e[0m%} %# ')"
```

or

```sh
PS1='%m'"$(check_sshfs_mp && print '%{\e[1;31m%} R %{\e[0m%}')"'%# '
```

Note that `print` is required to turn `\e`s into actual escape characters and the `%{...%}` form is needed to avoid the prompt code to misbehave. Reference: `zsh` FAQ: [How do I get coloured prompts on my colour xterm?](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html#l42)

If you prefer to have the check performed every time the primary prompt is set, you can avoid adding a hook function to `chpwd_functions` and add to your `.zshrc`:

```sh
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
export PS1='%m$(check_sshfs_mp && print "%{\e[1;31m%} R %{\e[0m%}")%# '
```

The `PROMPT_SUBST` option is needed to enable command substitution in prompt displaying. Reference: [Prompt Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Prompt-Expansion) in The Z Shell Manual.

Comment: Thanks, probably I got what you mention, I'll test it tomorrow.

Comment: I need to bring this `check_sshfs_mp && PS1='%m %F{red}R%f %# '` into `PS1/PROMPT` itself like PS1=`<...>check_sshfs_mp &&  %F{red}R%f %<..>` but how? Because I would bring it in `$( )` due to check_sshfs_mp is a function and `PS1` wouldn't understand `%F{red}R%f %` part if I put it in `$( )`.

Comment: I think I'll use `$()` and `print` to print out red `R`. Thanks.

Comment: But I still would like a solution that avoid loading `colors` zsh function to get `R` red.

Comment: I'm not completely understanding what you are trying to achieve, so I dont' know how to update my answer... but here are a few options: 1) To use escape sequences instead of color names, you can assign `PS1` in `chpwd_check_sshfs_mp` as: `check_sshfs_mp && PS1="$(print '%m %{\e[1;31m%}R%{\e[0m%} %# ')"`. `print` is needed to interpret escape sequences. You may rewrite this as: `PS1='%m'"$(check_sshfs_mp && print '%{\e[1;31m%} R %{\e[0m%}')"'%# '`. (cont.)

Comment: (cont'd) 2) `check_sshfs_mp` is called within a `chpwd` hook function to avoid unnecessarily running it any time the prompt is displayed. But you are free not to use the `chpwd_check_sshfs_mp` function and just put `setopt PROMPT_SUBST; export PROMPT='%m$(check_sshfs_mp && print '"'"'%{\e[1;31m%} R %{\e[0m%}'"'"')%# ';` in your `.zshrc`. The `PROMPT_SUBST` option is needed to enable command substitution in prompt displaying.

Comment: Thanks, in subshell it should be `print "\e[1;31m R \e[0m"`.

Comment: @TuyenPham It works, but there are reasons for using single quoted `%{...}` expressions. See the last paragraph of [this zsh FAQ item](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html#l42). It may be ok to use simple `"`s instead of the clunky `'"'"'`s needed to enclose the expression in single quotes, tough.

Answer (score 2):

Along the line of what @fra.san suggested, you can modify your LOCAL prompt by tweaking `PS1` so it reflects the fact that a folder in the path was mounted using `sshfs`.

First check that yr terminal supports color prompts. Include the following in yr `~/.kshrc` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
# Option is turned off by default to not distract the user.
force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # you have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). If support lacks use `setf` rather than `setaf`.
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=""
    fi
fi
```

Next, every time you mount a remote volume on your local FS with the wrapper `sshfs_wrp`, automatically append the path to that mounted remote volume to a temporary file, e.g. `/tmp/tmp_rem_vol`. You can do so with a simple wrapper to the sshfs command:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
# script name: sshfs_wrp   # wrapper for sshfs
mount_path="$( echo "$@"| cut -d" " -f $# )"  # usually last parameter to `sshfs`
# Note: above will break when parameters passed to sshfs_wrp 
# contain blanks between quotes. 
echo "$mount_path" >> /tmp/tmp_rem_vol
sshfs "$@" 
exit 0
```

Make sure the script is executable and its location is reachable with the PATH environment variable.

Next, define a function in your `~/.kshrc` or `~/.bashrc` to set a flag variable, `remFlag`, to `[R]` in case the string `"$(pwd)"` indicates you currently work inside a remote volume subtree, previously mounted with `sshfs_wrp`. I used `case` for portability. 
**EDIT:** *Note that as soon as you find a match in the `case` pattern match section, you must exit the while loop.*

```
function check_rem_vol () {
    if [ -s /tmp/tmp_rem_vol ] ; then
        while read rem_vol; do
            case "$(pwd)" in 
                # check whether pwd contains sshfs_wrp-mounted volume 
                *"${rem_vol}"*) remFlag="[R]" ; break  ;;  
                *) remFlag="" ;;
            esac
        done < /tmp/tmp_rem_vol
    else
        remFlag=""
    fi
    echo "$remFlag"
}
```

Finally, modify yr prompt `PS1` in yr `~/.kshrc` or `~/.bashrc`, by including the remote volume flag, `rem_vol`, in bright green in the prompt in case some remote volume was mounted using `sshfs_wrp`.

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    # For Debian based systems only
    #PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[0;38;5;166m\][\#/\!]\[\e[1;34m\] \w\[\e[38;5;46m\] \$(check_rem_vol)\[\e[1;38;5;166m\]>\[\e[0m\]"

    # For Archlinux
    PS1="\\[\\e[0;38;5;166m\\][\\#/\\!]\\[\\e[1;34m\\] \\w\\[\\e[38;5;46m\\] \$(check_rem_vol)\\[\\e[1;38;5;166m\\]\\> \\[\\e[0m\\]"
else
    # For Debian based systems only
    #PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
    #PS1="${debian_chroot:+}[\#/\!] \[\w \$(check_rem_vol)\]>"

    # For Archlinux
    PS1="[\\#/\\!] \\[\\w \$(check_rem_vol)\\]>"
fi
export PS1
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

This solution can be improved to reduce the number of moving parts and to improve the creation of the `/tmp/tmp_rem_vol` temporary file, or files, in case more than one ssh connection coexist and remote volumes are mounted from different remote hosts.

This should work both for one ssh connection, within a `bash` or `ksh` shell, on Debian or Arch Lx platforms.

When un-mounting the remote volume(s), or at session logout, or when closing the ssh connection, you should also take care of erasing `/tmp/tmp_rem_vol` to avoid persistence problem. You will find plenty of references and tips out there to automate that as well.

HTH

Comment: What would be the case when I have multiple `remote mountpoints` on the system? I assume this command `*"${rem_vol}"*) remFlag="[R]"  ;; ` will match against each line in `tmp` file, and I think we'd need to clean the `tmp` file in case of no `remote mountpoint`?

Comment: @TuyemPham: In case of multiple remote mountpoints, see my edit above. I modified the script so you can exit the `while read` loop at the first match. And yes, you should clean up with  `\rm -f /tmp/tmp_rem_vol 2> /dev/null` upon logging out. When there is no remote vol mount point or if you do not use the wrapper `sshfs_wrp`,`/tmp/tmp_rem_vol` is simply not created.