# Setting temporary bash aliases when entering a folder

Tags: bash, shell, alias

Sometimes I like to have very customized bash aliases and maybe keybindings when I enter on a folder (can be a project where I'm used to type lots of commands from CLI).

Lets suppose when I enter a folder like "projectAlpha/" I expect some custom aliases like:

- `alias doTaskX='./app arg1 arg2...|filter arg1 arg2...'`
- ...

More than it I was thinking of:

- Display a helpful message showing aliases and common commands
- Displaying some common custom keybindings for my project

But as soon as I leave the root of my project these settings become unavailable.

What is the best approach to do it today?

Comment: came a thought here now to use one alias for "cd" in ~/.bashrc, one alias to enter in one directory  and starts a new bash that reads the hidden .bashrc in that directory...

Comment: Near-duplicate: [Execute bash scripts on entering a directory](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21363/execute-bash-scripts-on-entering-a-directory)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bash has special variable `PROMPT_COMMAND` which content is executed every time *after* the command is executed, so you can set it as follows:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='[[ "$PWD" = /tmp ]] && { alias ll=ls; echo "Remember: ll=ls"; } || { unalias ll 2>/dev/null; }'
```

From now on every time you will be in the `/tmp` directory alias `ll` will be created and in all other directories it will be removed.

---

Probably more practical is to gather all your aliases and other stuff in one function (say `makealias`) and all unaliases in the other function `makeunalias` which you can run depending on your needs, something like

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='[[ "$PWD" = /tmp ]] && makealias || makeunalias 2>/dev/null'
```

Notice that stderr redirection is present only to prevent some useless in this case alerts.

Comment: ty, i'll try it. +1 (if i could up)

Comment: @user3697611 You don't need any reputation to accept the answer to your own question. Click on the check mark next to the answer.