# How to define alias only for some directory?

Tags: bash, alias, cd-command

I want to define some `alias iex="iex -S mix"` only for one directory - this alias should work only when I `cd`'ed to this directory. Another requirement - this functionality should be placed inside this directory, `hook` file or something other, because I want to share this directory as a git repo.

How can I do that?

Comment: Would you be ok if it was a function instead?

Comment: And it should only work in one specific directory -- not any subdirectory?

Comment: Similar: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21363/117549

Comment: Yes, only in one specific directory

Comment: Any shell or specific to one or more?

Comment: Jeff, bash only...

Comment: I suspect that an alias or function, like [bashBedlam's](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/311728/117549) is as close as you can get, as shells don't natively pick up functionality from each new directory. My 2 cents: put the alias or function definition into the documentation for your repo and let people add it to their own dot-files.

Comment: If you want to manage different shell environments for different projects/workspaces/whatever (which involves the two things you seem to be after: storing a project directory and custom aliases when working within it), you chould try using [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator).

Answer (score 7):

If you want `iex` to *only* work in one directory and *never* anywhere else try this:

```
alias iex='[ $(pwd) = /path/to/special/dir ] && iex –S mix'
```

If you want `iex` to work differently in other directories try it like this:

```
alias iex='[ $(pwd) = /path/to/special/dir ] && iex –S mix || iex'
```

Comment: This is an abuse of aliases. With this kind of thing, it is time to consider a function.

Answer (score -2):

My current development version of Bourne Shell (bosh) implements this feature since 6 jears. Check the man page:

http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html

and have a look at `local persistent aliases` - aliases local to a directory and persistent because they are kept in a file `.locals` of the related directory.

I am interested in feedback, in special whether there should also be `.locals.#`, where # is the user id of the user that is allowed to use them.