# Run git fetch after any cd command

Tags: bash, zsh, git, cd-command

I need to run git fetch after any cd command in the background and only if I'm in a git directory.

Comment: hi and welcome to Stack Exchange! I'm answering your question since it's easy, but in the future, please demonstrate to us that you've already made an attempt at solving your problem before coming here. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There are three parts to this:

1. Run some code on changing the current directory. In zsh, you put this code in the [`chpwd` function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-chpwd), or a function with a different name in the `chpwd_functions` array ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484741/customize-zsh-prompt-to-separately-show-tail-of-current-working-dir/484756#484756)). See [Execute bash scripts on entering a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21363/execute-bash-scripts-on-entering-a-directory/21364#21364) for a bash implementation.
2. Detect git working copies. Since you're only interested in git, [you can run `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command). There are more advanced frameworks to detect version control if you're interested in other version control systems.
3. Run `git fetch`.

Here's a `chpwd` implementation that runs `git fetch` when changing into a git repository.

```
chpwd () {
  set -- "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>/dev/null)"
  # If cd'ing into a git working copy and not within the same working copy
  if [ -n "$1" ] && [ "$1" != "$vc_root" ]; then
    vc_root="$1"
    git fetch
  fi
}
chpwd
```

This code goes in your shell startup script: `.zshrc` for zsh, `.bashrc` for bash (in bash you also need [the wrappers to call `chpwd` on a directory change](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21363/execute-bash-scripts-on-entering-a-directory/21364#21364)).

Comment: To avoid show of fatal error inside no git foldeers I changed this `set -- "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)" 2>/dev/null` into `set -- "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>/dev/null)"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function:

```
function cd() {
    builtin cd "$@"
    if [[ -d .git ]]; then
        git fetch &
    fi
}
```

Add this to your shell's startup file.

There are a couple things that are going on here:

1. First we use `function cd() {` to override the builtin `cd` behavior with our own custom code.
2. Obviously we still want to change the directory, so we do that first - we prefix it with `builtin`* so that the shell uses the builtin `cd` instead of recursively calling our custom `cd()` function, and we provide it with `$@` as the arguments, which gets expanded by the shell to all arguments provided to the function.
3. We test if we're in a git repository^ by testing if the `.git` directory exists, and if it does we run `git fetch`, telling the shell to put it in the background by appending `&`.

Note that the output of `git fetch` will still be sent to the terminal. If you wish to discard it you can use this instead:

```
git fetch & 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

This redirects stderr into stdout, then sends stdout to `/dev/null`.

[*]: Note that `builtin` isn't in POSIX and therefore this solution isn't portable across all shells

[^]: This fails if the git repository is bare, but you almost certainly aren't going to have a bare repository on your drive, so who cares

Comment: That doesn't deal with pushd, with the multi-argument form of `cd`, etc. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21363/execute-bash-scripts-on-entering-a-directory/21364#21364 for a more robust implementation.

Comment: My shell doesn't support `command` so I renamed the function and just directly call `cd "$@"` which appears to be working correctly however, catching stderr and stdout doesn't capture the command done output from the shell like :  `[3]  + done       git fetch 2>&1 > /dev/null`   any suggestions on capturing that?

Comment: @Gilles OP didn't ask about `pushd` and I thought $@ would expand to all arguments, hence handling the multi-argument form of `cd`. no?

Comment: @north.mister you didn't specify your shell. since you mentioned bash and zsh I assumed it was one of the two - if you need code for a different shell, you should have said so.

Comment: edited the answer to use `builtin` as that's probably more appropriate (and what I was thinking of in the first place)

Comment: The shell is zsh, however it's a custom internal distro of Linux (if that affects anything) but a question I have is why we need command/builtin.  If our function isn't named cd then we aren't overriding default cd behavior so a bare cd should work, right?

Comment: @north.mister I've no idea then; you should probably ask your local system administrator. if you don't name your function `cd`, then there's no reason to use `command` or `builtin`. but the function in the example _is_ named `cd`, hence the use of `builtin`.

Comment: Sorry, right, no problem with multiple arguments. `command` instead of `builtin` is fine. But there are other problem: this doesn't cope with errors in `cd`; this won't do anything if you change into a subdirectory of the git clone.

Answer (score -1):

make a function in your .bashrc or .zshrc file that is in your home directory.

Add the following to the bottom of the file:

```
cd_fetch() {
    command cd "$@"
    if [ -d .git ]; then
        git fetch & 
    fi
}
alias cdg=cd_fetch
```

Now close and re-open your terminal or run `source ~/.zshrc` and now you can change directory with the command `cdg` that you just aliased.

Also if you don't want to use `cdg` and want to use just `cd` change the alias definition to `alias cd=cd_fetch`.

This approach will still output all that git fetch normally do, to silence it replace the `git fetch &` line for `git fetch 2>&1 >/dev/null &`.

Comment: This doesn't deal with pushd or with failure of `cd`; see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21363/execute-bash-scripts-on-entering-a-directory/21364#21364 for a more robust implementation. This doesn't handle changing to a subdirectory of the git repository.