# Run shell script when navigating to directory with cd

Tags: bash, shell, cd-command

Is it available to set script to run in a particular directory, when you `cd` into it?

For example if `/foo` is a directory with `git` project, is it possible, when `cd /foo` automatically run `git status` or some `npm` scripts?

Please don't link answer to strictly to `git`, imagine that could be any other command/script.

Comment: For the git part, you may want to adapt https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320671/run-git-fetch-after-any-cd-command/320695#320695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways you can do this is via `alias` command:

```
alias cdgit="cd /foo; git status"
```

Then you execute `cdgit` and you go to directory `/foo` and exec `git status`

Answer (score 9):

You can replace `cd` with a function which adds any processing you want:

```
cd() {
    builtin cd "$@"
    # Do whatever you want here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I use something similar to Stephen Kitt's answer in my `.bashrc`:

```
function cd() {
  command cd "$@" || return

  if [[ -d .git ]]
  then
    git status --short
  else
    ls -al
  fi
}
```

You can create additional conditions to handle different things as needed.

NOTE: since we're clobbering the reference to the `cd` command, you have to use `command cd`, `builtin cd`, or `\cd` to prevent the function from calling itself and recursing forever.  For this reason some might find it useful to rename this function.