# Automatically source a file when `cd` into a specific directory

Tags: bash, zsh, alias

I have couple of utility commands-and-aliases that are generic enough in any directory for my own requirement. But there are certain directory e.g. 'build', where I need a custom behaviour.

To do this, I have created a different file in those directories, that contain the modifications with same name of functions and aliases (so that I don't need to remember, new names).

Currently I manually source the files, after cd'ing into the specific directory

```
source custom_aliases_n_fns
```

This is working well, but I'm looking to automate this sourcing of file.

Is there a way to source a file on cd'ing into specific directory?

Note: I went with this approach, as I don't want to change the system wide user-aliases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute bash scripts on entering a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21363/execute-bash-scripts-on-entering-a-directory)

Answer (score 7):

In `zsh`, you can use the `chpwd` special hook function which is invoked any time the current working directory changes:

```
custom_aliases_n_fns_already_sourced=false
chpwd() {
  if
    ! $custom_aliases_n_fns_already_sourced &&
      [[ $PWD = /some/dir && -f custom_aliases_n_fns ]]
  then
    source ./custom_aliases_n_fns
    custom_aliases_n_fns_already_sourced=true
  fi
}
```

I wouldn't recommend blindly sourcing files in *any* directory (hence the check for `$PWD = /some/dir`) as that could be abused.

Instead of changing the one and only `chpwd` hook, you can also do:

```
myhook() {
  if
    [[ $PWD = /some/dir && -f custom_aliases_n_fns ]]
  then
    source ./custom_aliases_n_fns
    chpwd_functions[(Ie)$0]=() # remove ourselves from the array
  fi
}
chpwd_functions+=(myhook)
```

This allows having more than one hook function called when the current working directory changes, and here instead of recording whether we've already sourced the file, we just remove our function from the list of `chpwd` hooks after the file has been sourced.

Answer (score 3):

**Untested**

In the target directories have `.myaliases` files that contain `alias foo=bar` commands, no blank lines, no #comments.

In your `~/.bashrc`:

```
function cd() {
if [[ -f ./.myaliases ]] ; then
  sed -e 's/^/un/;s/=.*$//' ./.myaliases >/tmp/myaliases.$$
  source /tmp/myaliases.$$
  rm /tmp/myaliases.$$
fi

builtin cd "$*"

if [[ .f ./.myaliases ]]; then
 source ./.myaliases
fi
```

This will first check if there is a `.myaliases` file in the current directory and, if there is, it will unalias any aliases from that file so you can move to a new directory with a clean slate. Then, after moving to the target directory, it checks for a `.myaliases` file there and, if it finds one, sources it. Read `man bash` for more details.

Comment: I would at least add a `[[ -O .myaliases ]]` check.

Comment: You wouldn't want to source a file in /tmp (a world writable directory!) with such a predictable name, especially considering you're not doing any error checking here. You could do `source <(sed ....)` here to avoid the tempfile.

Comment: Should be `"$@"`, not `"$*"`. You'd also want to check report the exit status of `builtin cd` to your caller. Any maybe not doing the unaliasing / aliasing if it fails.

Comment: You have a missing `}`, `.f` typo

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this template?
from .bashrc:

```bsh
PS1+='$([ \w = ~ ] && command || another command)'
```

Both env variables `$PWD` and escape prompt `\w` sequences work.
This is quite consistent with what you are looking for, but I'm not sure about the correct approach in general.

Comment: That breaks when the current working directory contains characters special to the shell including space (even making it a command injection vulnerability when you cd into the wrong directory). Also the command the OP wants to use is `source`, and `$(....)` introduces a sub shell, so `source` will fails to set aliases or functions like the name of the OP's sourced file suggests it  does.