# Any way to apply .tmux.conf in the cwd automatically?

Tags: tmux

I have different projects and use bunch of tmux panels to manage them.

Unfortunately it's hard to keep track which panel has which project folder.

Is there any way to apply `.tmux.conf` in a folder automatically when I `cd` to it in a panel?
Like setting colors:

```
#set inactive/active window styles
set -g window-style 'fg=colour247,bg=colour236'
set -g window-active-style 'fg=colour250,bg=black'

# set the pane border colors 
set -g pane-border-style 'fg=colour235,bg=colour238' 
set -g pane-active-border-style 'fg=colour51,bg=colour236'
```

The above conf has `-g` switch that sets colors globally I guess.
So any way to have such config to set colors in a folder and have the config file in that folder?
If no, can I at least configure folders' colors in the `~/.tmux.config`?

I'm not good with Linux/Tmux so some more detailed help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's two things going on here.
You want to

1. Run an arbitrary command upon `cd`ing into a directory, and
2. Run a `tmux` command that alters the fg/bg colors.

Both of these are solved problems.

1. [Execute bash scripts on entering a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21363/execute-bash-scripts-on-entering-a-directory)
2. `$ tmux set -g window-style 'fg=colour247,bg=colour236'`

Additionally, some folks like to
[customize](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/customize-bash-prompt)
their bash prompt when they `cd`.
Or send an ANSI escape sequence, as this python function demonstrates:

```
def set_title(title):
  '''Use ANSI escape codes to set xterm title bar.'''
  sys.stdout.write('\033]0;%s\007' % title)
```

[Let us know](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)
which details you wind up settling on.